# npx @react-native-community/cli doctor wrong JDK

Tags: react-native

When I run this command from my mac
`npx @react-native-community/cli doctor`

I get this funny unrecognized java version :

```
Common
 âœ“ Node.js
 âœ“ yarn
 âœ“ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode
```

Android
âœ– JDK

- Version found: **1.8.0_242-release**
- Version supported: **>= 8**

When I execute :
`react-native info`

I get :
info Fetching system and libraries information...

```
System:  
    OS: macOS 10.15.5  
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz  
    Memory: 226.40 MB / 16.00 GB  
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh  
  Binaries:  
    Node: 12.18.2 - /usr/local/bin/node  
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn  
    npm: 6.14.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm  
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman  
  Managers:  
    CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /Users/emmanuelharel/.gem/bin/pod  
  SDKs:  
    iOS SDK:  
      Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2  
    Android SDK:  
      API Levels: 28, 30  
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.0  
      System Images: android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom  
      Android NDK: Not Found  
  IDEs:  
    Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223  
    Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild  
  Languages:  
    Java: 1.8.0_242-release - /usr/bin/javac  
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python  
  npmPackages:  
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found  
    react: ~16.11.0 => 16.11.0   
    react-native: ~0.62.2 => 0.62.2   
  npmGlobalPackages:  
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Has anyone an idea why react native cli is not able to get that java 1.8 and 8 are the "same"?

Comment: Hey, did you fix this, I am having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1255
There is a pull request #1395 just in for this to fix it, so it might be accepted soon and make its way into a patch.